# Deleted Ubuntu partition= error no such partition grub rescue

Tags: grub2, windows-8

Hey so I deleted the Ubuntu partition on my hdd from Windows 8 to have more free space, but my computer is still trying to boot with grub. Can I change the boot process so it boots up w Windows? I don't have Windows8 disk to boot from can I change it in bios?